# Add VBA code to excel files using Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel

Title is pretty straightforward. How can I add VBA code to an Excel file using Excel interop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to save your VBA code in a ".bas" file? Then you can try to add the code programmatically via Excel interop.

If that's not working, Why not you just simple add the following code when the `Workbook_Open` event fires:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim sModulePath As String

    sModulePath = "path"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import Filename:=sModulePath
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, that there are more than 200 files that need to be updated. It was not my design mistake ;) But I will try to find some examples regarding import of bas files. Thanks again.